# ¿Porque no me acepta la importacion de ciertos registros de excel a mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, importación

Resulta que intento hacer una importación de excel a mysql ya lo produje pero resulta que los registros que tienen ñ o tilde no me hace la insercion  a la base de datos , y esos ñ y tildes estan en el excel luego los importo , adjunto código de importacion de excel a mysql, probablemente el error es de UTF-8 pero ya lo tengo a UTF-8 no veo el problema, de antemano Muchas gracias!!

```html
<?php
include "../../config/bd.php";
$tipo       = $_FILES['dataExcel']['type'];
$tamanio    = $_FILES['dataExcel']['size'];
$archivotmp = $_FILES['dataExcel']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES["dataExcel"]["name"];
$lineas     = file($archivotmp);
$tipoExtension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if ($tipoExtension == "csv") {
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($lineas as $linea) {
        $cantidad_registros = count($lineas);
        $cantidad_regist_agregados =  ($cantidad_registros - 1);

        if ($i != 0) {

            $datos = explode(";", $linea);


            $fecha_registro                = !empty($datos[0]) ? ($datos[0]) : '';
            $materia               = !empty($datos[1])  ? ($datos[1]) : '';
            $hora_registro               = !empty($datos[2])  ? ($datos[2]) : '';
            $usuario                = !empty($datos[3])  ? ($datos[3]) : '';
            $cod_doc               = !empty($datos[4])  ? ($datos[4]) : '';

            if (!empty($cod_doc)) {
                $checkcod_duplicidad = ("SELECT cod_doc FROM daem WHERE cod_doc='" . ($cod_doc) . "' ");
                $ca_dupli = mysqli_query($con, $checkcod_duplicidad);
                $cant_duplicidad = mysqli_num_rows($ca_dupli);
            }

            //No existe Registros Duplicados
            if ($cant_duplicidad == 0) {

                $insertarData = "INSERT INTO daem(fecha_registro,materia,hora_registro,usuario,cod_doc) VALUES('$fecha_registro','$materia','$hora_registro','$usuario','$cod_doc')";
                $resultado =  mysqli_query($con, $insertarData);
                if ($resultado) {

                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                    window.location.href="daem.php";
                    </script>';
                } else {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("No se ha insertado la informacion,revise los campos de su importación excel, que cumpla con las condiciones
                    ,fecha : año-mes-dia  y hora válida, y que las columnas esten acorde al formato solicitado");
                    window.location.href="daem.php";
                    </script>';
                }
            }
            /**Caso Contrario actualizo el o los Registros ya existentes*/
            else {

                echo '<script type="text/javascript">
               alert("Hay un registro o registros que tienen el mismo codigo de documento,revise e importe nuevamente el archivo");
               window.location.href="daem.php";
               </script>';
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("El documento no tiene extension csv , reintente nuevamente");
       window.location.href="daem.php";
      </script>';
}
```

Se puede observar que estoy recorriendo las filas del excel en el codigo me hace la funcion pero como dije no me acepta los campos que contienen tildes y ñ por lo cual no se si es problema de excel o problema de mysql u php , de antemano Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Ignoren el comentario de caso contrario :)

Comment: Ya vi mi error  jajaja , aunque no se si llamarle error, resulta que tengo que guardar el archivo excel como un cvs con utf-8 y delimitado por comillas , en mi caso me salte la opcion utf-8 y fui por delimitado por comillas solamente,no se si alguien sabe como transformar el excel a utf-8 sin necesidad de guardarlo de esa forma , de antemano Muchas Gracias!